# Angular 2: Populate checkbox list comparing two lists and initially check some items

Tags: javascript, angular

In my Angular 2 application in the service file I have following.

**service.ts**

```
getUserSelections() {
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/selection/selections').map((res: Response) => res.json());
}

getSavedSelections() {
    let params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams();
    params.set('access_token', localStorage.getItem('access_token'));
    return this.http.get('http://localhost:8080/interest/user/selections', { search: params }).map((res: Response) => res.json());
}
```

**getUserSelections** returns following json array.

```
[{
    "key": "test1",
    "val": 1.0
  }, {
    "key": "test2",
    "val": 1.0
  }, {
    "key": "test3",
    "val": 1.0
  }]
```

**getSavedSelections** returns following.

```
[{
    "key": "test2",
    "val": 1.0
  }, {
    "key": "test3",
    "val": 1.0
  }]
```

I don't need to call these two services separately. Once I call **getUserSelection** I need to call both one after the other if first service success. Then I want to compare these two json arrays, 1st array includes all the items, 2nd one includes some items from 1st array. SO I need to check which items are included in the 2nd array and add new attribute as "selected (true or false)" to the items of the 1st array. Ultimately, need to return one array as below.

```
[{
    "key": "test1",
    "val": 1.0,
    "selected": false
  }, {
    "key": "test2",
    "val": 1.0,
    "selected": true
  }, {
    "key": "test3",
    "val": 1.0,
    "selected": true
  }]
```

Any suggestions are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the **map** function on the first array. It will return a new array with the callback function called on each item.

```
let result = Array1.map((elem1) => {
  elem1.selected = false;
  Array2.forEach((elem2) => {
    if (elem2.key === elem1.key)
      elem1.selected = true;
  });
  return elem1;
});
```

Comment: These two arrays are dynamic

Comment: What do you mean ? The key to compare is dynamic ?

Comment: JSON array items my be changed

Comment: Okay, but it's not a problem, if the key to compare is the same this will work the same. If you need more flexibility you can wrap this snippet in a function that accept a key or array of key to compare ;)